# Meet us at Cisco Live 2014

Tags: discussion

Fellow Networkers… if you're going to Cisco Live US this year, and want to meet up during the week please add your name below.  I'll be there, and I think Daniel Dib will as well.  This would be a good opportunity to associate names with faces.

Comment: Yeah. I'll be there, would be nice to meet you Mike. Hopefully some more people from here will join.

Comment: Maybe I'll be back in the states next year.  Enjoy, guys.

Comment: Keep me posted; I'm planning on being at the Networkers conference -- still haven't gotten used to the Cisco Live rebranding.

Comment: @generalnetworkerror can you meet us in the social media hub at 11:35 today?

Comment: Sorry Mike.  I got food poisoning the night before that caused me to miss past of the conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  We met today at Cisco Live.

Comment: I down voted because you weren't at any Junos conferences this year :)

Comment: @jwbensley We are an all Cisco and F5 shop; I have no need for a Junos conference.    Furthermore, my experience with Junos left me thinking they're nothing more than another Cisco.  Not tested any better, not implemented any better... so why bother?  Spare me the fanboy frothing... I simply don't need another vendor to manage, another CLI to learn, and another feature-jigsaw-puzzle to assemble

Comment: Chill my friend, I could have named any vendor, it was merely a tounge in cheek commment meant to be friendly banter. I would have said Hello if I could have made it to Cisco Live.

Comment: You take risks when you troll. Perhaps you'd find more success by saying "Wish I could have been at CLUS this year" ;)